# After installing Meshlab, starting "cmd" says MeshLabServer

Tags: meshlab

After installing Meshlab, a run "cmd" brings up a window that used to be titled "Command Prompt" but is now titled "MeshLabServer" and starts in C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab.

Uninstalling MeshLab does NOT put it back.

I'd rather MeshLab didn't mess with run "cmd" at all. If it wants a command prompt window pointing to C:\Program Files\VCG\Meshlab, make a separate entry (in, I assume, the Registry).

Please tell me how to put this back to "normal".

Comment: I think it would be convenient to ask on http://superuser.com instead SO

Comment: This is probably a problem with how MeshLab is modifying the PATH. But if you uninstall MeshLab that installation path should not exist anymore.

Comment: From the original post: Uninstalling MeshLab does NOT put it back.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to Start menu and right-click on this "cmd" (Mesh Lab Server now). Choose Open file location. The only thing you should do is remove Meshlab Server shortcut. Now you have normal command prompt. 
Worked without any rebooting for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue! After some searching, I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/145), where someone gives a solution. Basically, MeshLab puts a link to cmd.exe in the Start Menu, which overrides the usual cmd.exe. The fix for this is to delete the `MeshLabServer.lnk` shortcut, which should be in one of these two directories (for me, it was in the second):

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MeshLab
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MeshLab
```

After a reboot, the issue was fixed.